# Video is blank but audio can be heard - Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I can successfully upload my video with the below code. But when i display the video in the view page it's blank.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {       
        if(Auth::check())
        {       
            if(Input::hasFile('video'))
            {
                $file = $request->file('video');
                $videomimes = ['video/mp4'];

                if (in_array($file->getMimeType() ,$videomimes)) {
                    $filevalidate = 'required|mimes:mp4';
                }

                $this->validate($request, [
                    'video' => $filevalidate,                        
                ]);

                $filename = 'Tag '.$request->input('tag_no').'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $request->death_video->move(public_path('/storage/videos'), $filename);

                $stock = Stock::create([
                        'tag_no' => $request->input('tag_no'),
                        'video'=> $filename,                                                              
                        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
                ]);               

                if($stock){
                    return redirect()->route('stocks.index')
                    ->with('success' , 'Stock created successfully');
                }
            }                                           
        }        
        return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error creating new Stock');        
    }
```

This is my schema:

```
Schema::create('stocks', function (Blueprint $table) {            

        $table->increments('tag_no');               
        $table->binary('video');                 

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->timestamps();            
    });
```

This is how i display video:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="/storage/videos/{{$stock->video}}" type="video/mp4">                   
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I can hear the audio but no visual is shown! How to solve this?

Comment: seems like html or browser issue, okay does video file have a visual ?, is it returning in correct file format ?, maybe removing all the spaces from filename will help like "Tag_filename.mp4"

Comment: maybe, $table->longText('video')

Comment: Hey i tried uploading another video... and now.. it showing... i guess the problem was with the video resolution.

Comment: Good, Let us know if there's a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are store video in public directory then try use URL helper

```
<source src="{{url('/storage/videos/'.$stock->video)}}" type="video/mp4">
```